# How to decrypt AesCryptoServiceProvider using JavaScript?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, encryption, cryptojs

I am using `EncryptStringToBytes_Aes` method from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to encrypt some data using custom passphrase like this:

```
string original = "some data to encrypt";
byte[] encrypted;

using (AesManaged aes = new AesManaged())
{
    // Prepare new Key and IV.
    string passphrase = "somepassphrase";
    byte[] saltArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("somesalt"); 
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfcKey = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passphrase, saltArray);
    aes.Key = rfcKey.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
    aes.IV = rfcKey.GetBytes(aes.BlockSize / 8);

    // Encrypt the string to an array of bytes. 
    encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(original, aes.Key, aes.IV);

    // Decrypt the bytes to a string. 
    string roundtrip = DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(encrypted, aes.Key, aes.IV);

    return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
}
```

and it works (`DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes` returns the original string).

My question is how do I decrypt `encrypted` using JavaScript if I have the same passphrase on the client-side as well? I tried using [CryptoJS](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) to decrypt it but had no success. The data gets encrypted in a webservice and I tried passing it to JS as a byte array, string, tried encoding it with various encodings but no matter what I did, I couldn't get the original string. What am I doing wrong here and how can I make this work? Is it even doable like this? Could the saltArray encoding or even the usage of the custom passphrase be the cause of my problems?

Here is for example one of my JS tries (using base64 encoding):

```
var decoded = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encrypted);
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(decoded, "somepassphrase");
```

*(edit: I meant to implement random salt later, once I got everything else wokring since it is easier to track what is going on that way)*

Comment: You're misusing CBC by always using the same IV.  The IV should be a sequence of random bytes and should never be reused.

Comment: @SLaks - using random salt would give me different IV everytime, that is what you are reffering to, right? I meant implementing random salt later, once everything else worked.

Comment: Correct.  You will need to transmit the IV along with each message.  (the IV does not need to be secret)

Comment: http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2009-06-11-cryptographic-right-answers.html

Comment: This sample is horrible because it reuses the IV. Doesn't this totally destroy security with CBC mode?

Comment: @SLaks - ok, thank you for your help, I will try it out first thing in the morning when I get to work.

Comment: @usr - yes, but I also wrote I would fix that part a bit later. This was only for testing if it worked at all or not. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I think the question is more about your CryptJS javascript than your c# code (although i agree with SLaks points about your c# code), CryptJS should have everything you need to decrypt your c# output,such as AES-CBC & PBKDF2.

Answer (score 0):

try using Stanford Javascript Crypto Library.
Link:http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/

Comment: The Stanford Javascript Crypto Library only uses CCM and OCB Block modes, neither of them are supported by `AesManaged`.